# getting more informations from sax validator

Tags: java, xml, groovy, xsd, sax

Can i get for example the node structure or something like this from the validator? Something like a listener or an handler. The exception is not enough. I have to select the node where the error occured. Thats what i build so far.

```
def factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI)
def schema = factory.newSchema(new StreamSource(new FileReader("src/import.xsd")))
def validator = schema.newValidator()
try {
    validator.validate(new StreamSource(new FileReader("src/import.xml")))
    println "everything is fine"
} catch(SAXException e) {   
    println e
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Validate when you parse. Here's the code in Java, looks like the translation to Groovy should be pretty straightforward:

```
InputStream xml = // …
InputStream xsd = // …

SchemaFactory xsFact = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
Schema schema = xsFact.newSchema(new StreamSource(xsd));

DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
dbf.setValidating(false);
dbf.setSchema(schema);
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

Document dom = db.parse(new InputSource(xml));
```

Comment: Okay, now i have the dom of the XML, but how do i know where the error was? I mean something like:

cvc-length-valid: Value 'aaaaaa' with length = '6' is not facet-valid with respect to length '5' for type 'stringLength5'.

Comment: SAXException tracks the line and column number of the error, so it relates back to the original file, not the element. After responding, I checked the sources to see if you could get more information by casting to the implementation type, but that does not appear to be the case. All I can say is I feel your pain; it's a definite oversight in the API.

Comment: And in case it wasn't clear: the 'db.parse()' call should be wrapped in a try/catch.

Comment: it was clear i wrapped it in try/catch :) sad that this isn't possible - thank you anytime for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the *SAXParseException* to get more errors or the [SAX locator](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/org/xml/sax/Locator.html) if you're implementing ContentHandler, and possibly a lexer. The exception will give you details about the error, line number.

```
try{
  ...
}
catch(SAXParseException e){
   int lineNumber = e.getLineNumber();
   int columnNumber = e.getColumnNumber();
   String message = e.getMessage();
   // do something
}
catch(SAXException e){
   // what should we do?
   // if we're implementing ContentHandler 
   // we can use the org.xml.sax.Locator to get more info
}
```

**Usually the column information from the Locator returns** *-1*. For offset precision, you'll have to either use an extended ContentHandler or a lexer:

- Get the line number of the error
- Estimate the position of the node with the line information, attributes(start tag, end tag) using a lexer or regular expressions or something else.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how much control you have over the environment, there is a somewhat clunky way to do this. The [Xerxes 2](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/) XML parser, which is a drop-in replacement for the default parser, has a property on the Validator to get the current node, so if you keep a reference to the Validator (as a field of an ErrorHandler that you set on the Validator, for example) you can get the node structure. Here's how I did it in Java:

```
...
  Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
  validator.setErrorHandler(new MyErrorHandler(validator));
...



public class MyErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
  private Validator validator;

  public AnnotatingErrorHandler(Validator v) {
    super();
    validator = v;
  }

  @Override
  public void error(SAXParseException e) throws SAXException {

    try {
      element = (Element)validator.getProperty("http://apache.org/xml/properties/dom/current-element-node");
    } catch (SAXNotRecognizedException e) {
      log(Level.SEVERE, "Xerxes 2 XML parser is required", saxnre);
    } catch (SAXNotSupportedException e) {
   ; // shouldn't happen in this context
    }
    ... // do stuff
  }
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Came across the same issue and resolved it by using the following.

1. Used SAXSource when using the validate method.
2. Used Implementation of error handler to capture SAXParseException.